# Electron.js - Send child process' spawn stdout data to renderer in realtime

Tags: node.js, electron, stdout, child-process, spawn

I have a simple node child process that invokes a script and that script takes time to output some information (kinda like how `ping` works).

```js
let command = spawn(
      execPath,
      [...args],
      { cwd: null, detached: false }
    );
```

Then I do a standard console.log for the stdout:

```js
command.stdout.on("data", (stdout) => {
      console.log("Realtime Output: ", stdout.toString());
    });
```

The issue is, I want to send this realtime output back to renderer process and show it on the frontend. I tried adding an `ipcRenderer.send()` inside the `command.stdout.on()` but it doesn't work, and the frontend shows `undefined` in console.log.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to send the `stdout` from `mainWindow` through [webContents](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents)

```js
 mainWindow.webContents.send('output', stdout.toString())
```

Comment: Thanks! The problem was in stdout, stdout data was empty and stderr was outputting the data instead.